# NSMutableData Plist for NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I am loading a plist via NSURLConnection into NSMutableData.
After that is done I want to read the PLIST into a NSMutableDictionary.
And then add the objects into my array to display them in a tableview.
But at the moment I don't know how to extract the data from NSMutableData into my NSMutableDictionary.
If I save the data local as plist on the iPhone in some folder and then read the plist into my Dictionary it works. But isn't there a way to do this directly?

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:receivedData];

    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];


    NSDictionary *myDictionary = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Beverage"];

    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    beverageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    beverageArray = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"Beverage"];

    NSLog(@"%@", beverageArray);

}
```

Before using NSURLConnection I used this which works:

```
- (void) makeDataBeverage {

    beverageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *beverageDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"beverage", nil)]];

    beverageArray = [beverageDic objectForKey:@"Beverage"];
```

Now I want to the same with using NSURLConnection.

Comment: Bad code formatting, my nemesis. So we meet again.... In all seriousness though, please work on your code formatting before you post, thanks!

Comment: Do you have any template for the data being transmitted? Is it an xml document?

Comment: Sorry for the bad code....just a beginner...the data which is load is a plist with dictionary and arrays

Comment: Frankly I do not know the correct answer because I never 'manually' parsed XML. If I had to go for a quick soltuion without knowing how to parse XML in Objective-C I would save the data into a file and then create the dictionary with dictionaryWithContentOfFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the complete data(*), you'll want to look into the [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/) class. Its `+propertyListWithData:options:format:error:` method should get you what you're looking for, and you can use the options parameter to get the results as a mutable dictionary or array.

(*)It sounds like you have the complete data, since you say you can write it to a file and then read it in using `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` or similar, but it doesn't look like you're guaranteed to get it from the code you've shown. You're creating a new data in `-connection:didReceiveData:`, but that delegate method can be called multiple times as the data arrives in pieces. (I'm guessing it just happened to arrive all in one piece for your testing... this may not always be true, especially on a mobile device.) Instead, you probably want to create an empty mutable data when you start your `NSURLConnection` (or in `-connection:didReceiveResponse:`), append to it in `-connection:didReceiveData:`, and parse it in `-connectiondidFinishLoading:`. Or even better, since the property list parser can't do anything with a partial data anyway, use the new `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]` if you're targeting iOS 5.0+.

Comment: Thanks that helped. You were right to look at NSPropertyListSerialization. I did it that way and it works fine.     `NSError *error;    
    NSData * tempData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
    NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;
    NSDictionary *temp = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:tempData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&plistFormat error:&error];
    beverageArray = [temp objectForKey:@"Beverage"];`